# Calculate Pearson's Coefficient for Multidimensional features

Tags: pandas, correlation, pearson

I have a pandas dataframe where each row corresponds to one sample and each column represents one feature. Now one of my columns is a string column which contains text like "This is a red apple". How can I convert this to a form that pearson's correlation matrix can be computed for this dataframe?
Similarly I have another column which takes in a list of identifiers.

Below is an example:

```
 id     text                   list_of_ids      score1 score2
 1.    "This is An apple"      [1, 2, 3, 4]     4.6.   1.0
 2.    "This is An orange"     [1, 5, 6]        5.2    1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
pd.concat([df, df['col1'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ')], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    An  This    apple   is  orange
0   This is An apple    [1, 2, 3, 4]    4.6 1.0 1   1   1   1   0
1   This is An orange   [1, 5, 6]   5.2 1.4 1   1   0   1   1
```

You can then drop the columns that you don't want using [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: What if the number of words can grow very large? Is this still the right way to compute correlation?